# ibm iot for electronics welcome page not working. Not showing fields for Auth Key,API Key and ORG ID

Tags: ibm-cloud, iot

ibm iot for electronics service welcome page not working. Not showing fields for Auth Key,API Key and ORG ID. I am following this iBM DOC
[https://console-regional.ng.bluemix.net/docs/starters/IoTElectronics-starter/iotelectronics_dashboard.html#iot4e_enabledashboard]

Comment: provide more information: what you see, error messages and so on

Comment: No there is not a single error I faced when I open ibmiotforelectronic service page.The page is suppose be like this .. [link] (https://console-regional.ng.bluemix.net/docs/starters/IoTElectronics-starter/iotelectronics_dashboard.html#iot4e_enabledashboard)  ... however when I open service there is no fields there.

Comment: I stuck at 3rd step when I need to enter the keys .. but rather I dont see anything where I can put in my values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the same issue if I deploy the IoT for Electronics Boilerplate in the US.  I see:

> Refused to display 'https://login.ng.bluemix.net/UAALoginServerWAR/oauth/authorize?state=4df328…ibmiotforelectronicsprod.mybluemix.net:443/rest/sso_dashboard?locale=en_IE' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

In the UK it works fine - you can use that region if you need it today.

Comment: Great!  They do need to fix US region but you and I will both get more SO points if you accept the answer.  It's how we say thanks on SO ;-). Also, fyi, your Q would have been better received by the reviewers if you had included an extract from Chrome-More Tools-Developer Tools with the error I posted. Or at least a screenshot.

Comment: Still faced an error even when I entered the values .. Binding IoT for Electronics and IoT Platform Update not successful

Comment: You should log a new Q for that.  Do it in chrome.  Run developer tools.  See if you see anything in Red basically, in the Console.  Add that to the Q. btw, US is fixed for me also now.